# My MySQL query with two JOINs does not work

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written the following query, which does not work. I want to know how to make it work. It is a two-JOIN query which fails to work.

```
SELECT oc_download.download_id, oc_product_to_download.download_id, oc_download_description.download_id
  FROM oc_download 
         LEFT JOIN oc_product_to_download
                ON oc_download.download_id = oc_product_to_download.download_id 
         LEFT JOIN
                   oc_download.download_id = oc_download_description.download_id
 WHERE oc_product_to_download.product_id = 89
```

With single JOIN it works, but adding the second JOIN it fails. here is the clean working one-JOIN query:

```
SELECT oc_download.download_id, oc_product_to_download.download_id, oc_download_description.download_id
  FROM oc_download 
         LEFT JOIN oc_product_to_download
                ON oc_download.download_id = oc_product_to_download.download_id
 WHERE oc_product_to_download.product_id = 89
```

How should I use multiple JOIN in one single query?

Comment: You are missing an `on` clause and table definition.

Comment: who has down-votted this :) interesting

Comment: -1. There is an  obvious syntax error in this query. And the question is unlikely to help any future visitors.

Comment: If you format your query (see adjusted question) you can see what you miss yourself more easily

Comment: @SalmanA . . . Those are perhaps good reasons to vote to close the question (there is, in fact, a close reason that is explicitly for that purpose).  However, that is not necessarily a reason to down vote it as well.

Comment: Mostafa, questions like this are best supplied with a table structure, so we can see how things are meant to join together. "Fails to work", "does not work" and "fails" is also not helpful - do you get no results? An error? If the latter, what is it?

Comment: If downvotes were based upon fact rather than opinion, what would be the point of them? Why are people so tetchy about downvotes? They serve to draw the poster's attention to the fact that there's some aspect of the post which deserves further attention.

Comment: Side note - that first `LEFT JOIN` is being turned into a regular `(INNER) JOIN` due to the condition in the `WHERE` clause.  Which one is correct is impossible for us to tell without more information.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the table name in the 2nd join

```
SELECT d.download_id, p.download_id, dd.download_id 
FROM oc_download d
LEFT JOIN oc_product_to_download p ON d.download_id = p.download_id 
LEFT JOIN oc_download_description dd ON d.download_id = dd.download_id 
WHERE p.product_id = 89
```

And your `where` clause turns your `left join` into an `inner join`. If you don't want that then change your query to

```
SELECT d.download_id, p.download_id, dd.download_id 
FROM oc_download d
LEFT JOIN oc_product_to_download p ON d.download_id = p.download_id 
                                  AND p.product_id = 89
LEFT JOIN oc_download_description dd ON d.download_id = dd.download_id
```

Answer (score 2):

This is your query fixed up a bit, using table aliases and proper `join` syntax:

```
SELECT od.download_id, opd.download_id, odd.download_id
FROM oc_download od LEFT JOIN
     oc_product_to_download opd
     ON od.download_id = opd.download_id LEFT JOIN
     oc_download_description odd
     od.download_id = odd.download_id
WHERE opd.product_id = 89;
```

You are using `left join`, but this appears to be unnecessary.  The `on` clause is undoing the first outer join, turning it into an inner join (unmatched rows would have a `NULL` value, which are filtered out by the `where` clause).  In fact, I would guess that your data has well defined foreign key relationships among the columns being joined.  If this is the case, you should use `inner join` (or just `join`) for the query:

```
SELECT od.download_id, opd.download_id, odd.download_id
FROM oc_download od JOIN
     oc_product_to_download opd
     ON od.download_id = opd.download_id JOIN
     oc_download_description odd
     od.download_id = odd.download_id
WHERE opd.product_id = 89;
```

The `left join` is misleading because it implies that some keys might not match.  You also run the risk of confusing the optimizer.